# Fetch data from Parent to the child from related List

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is my requirement :- 
I have a proposal page which is in master relationship with Opportunity. 
So for an opportunity there are multiple proposals. When user create an opportunity and from that View page of opportunity (Related List functionality)  when i create a proposal some information should be auto populated like Opportunity Name , Product bla bla ....

How to achieve this functionality

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a custom button called new and add like :

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom button called new(apart from standard) and add like : https://na1.salesforce.com/{object_prefix}/e?CF00N900000022p5z={parent_object_name}&CF00N900000022p5z_lkid={parent_object_id}&saveURL=/{parent_object_id}&retURL=/{parent_object_id}

Notice that parent name is CF00N900000022p5z and parent id is CF00N900000022p5z_lkid and a new parameter saveURL to redirect the page after user hit Save button. which is working for me, try out

Comment: and adding to the above refer this page : http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2015/03/the-salesforce-admins-toolbox-populating-fields-with-a-custom-button.html